# Swift | viewController.type does not have a member named 'rssTextField'

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, MenuDelegate, CoreDataManagerDelegate { 

     @IBOutlet weak var rssTextField: UITextField!
     var rssField = rssTextField.text  
    // viewController.type does not have a member named 'rssTextField'
}
```

How I can resolve it ? thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign this outlet to `rssFiled` declaraction directly. Move this code to e.g. inside your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, MenuDelegate, CoreDataManagerDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var rssTextField: UITextField?
     var rssField = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let text = self.rssTextField.text {
           self.rssField = text;
        }
    }
```

Btw maybe this assign value process should be triggered on some button action, but it is only hint for you. Because this outlet on `viewDidLoad` will not have any string value.

Comment: Thank's it works, but when i hit run the app crash and the console say : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value